# NameError: name 'move' is note defined (function)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, import, nameerror

Hey I've been working on a labyrinth game and I wrote a function to make the character (which is a robot) move. The problem is that Python says my function is not define

> NameError: name 'move' is not defined

but I defined it and I imported the function file in the main file.
This is my function file (modified so it's a little bite cleaner)

```
import pickle

from classes.labyrinthe import *
from roboc import *
from carte import *
from creer_labyrinthe import *

def move(oldLab, direction, steps):
    global isOnExit
...
return oldLab
```

And this is my main file (again modified...)

```
import os

from classes.carte import Carte

from fonctions.receiveRobotMoves import *
from fonctions.move import *
...
isOnExit = False
while isOnExit == False: #Tant que le robot n'est pas sur la sortie...
    #On demande au joueur la direction qu'il veut prendre
    receiveRobotMoves()

    #On fait avancer le robot
    conteneur = move(Labyrinthe, movesInformation['direction'], 
movesInformation['steps'])
    #On met à jour le labyrinthe
    Labyrinthe = conteneur
```

Could you please tell me what I can do to make it work.

Comment: `from functions import move` ?

Comment: It's from "fonctions" though.

Comment: Thank you guys it worked perfectly ! I wish I could give some of that reputation for that :D